# Kali linux does not boot in gui

Tags: boot, terminal, graphical-user-interface

I got kali linux installed on my pc for a while but now linux will not boot in gui mode , only in text mode ( terminal ).

I get no errors on booting it goes directly to the login screen .

Hope you can help me and yes I tried googling it.

Comment: What error messages?

Comment: Try using "startx" command after logging in.

Comment: I had the same issue on VBox 5.2.2 with Kali 4.14 and nvidia card on the hosting pc win10 pro :  I disabled 3D and works now like a charm...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Type:

```
gdm3
```

into the command line. This should start the gui.

If this does not work:

```
login to tty1
apt-get update
apt-get upgrade -y
apt-get install -f gdm3
```

**UPDATE:**

I found some more to this workaround which may help you:

```
apt-get install chkconfig
chkconfig --level 2 gdm3
gdm3
```

Now the system should take you to the graphical mode.

Other users also managed to get to the graphical mode just by typing:

```
X
```

Comment: non of it works

Comment: Any error messages after typing gdm3?

Comment: I edited the answer by the way. Please check if this works.

Comment: Try ‘startx’. Worked for me in 2019